# Toda vez que inicio um servidor o mongoose faz uma conexão desnecessária ao banco de dados

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Boa noite pessoal!

Estou iniciando na área e como primeiro objetivo resolvi criar um e-commerce simples, só que toda vez que inicio meu servidor, ele executa uma conexão ao banco de dados de forma desnecessária, fiquei com a pulga atrás da orelha, pois afinal, isso seria seguro? Não tenho que fechar a conexão toda vez que fizer uma consulta ou algo do tipo?

Se alguém puder me explicar esses conceitos e tals, segue meu código

[image: Coloquei um console.log para exibir a mensagem]

Abaixo segue o trecho onde faço a conexão, o que queria saber seria mais um conceito mesmo, para não cometer erros bobos no futuro, pode até ser que a minha pergunta não faça muito sentido para o pessoal experiente

```js
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/didixo', {useNewUrlParser: true}).then(function(){
  console.log("Conectado a base de dados")
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log("Erro ao conectar a base de dados: " + err)
})
```

```html
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB funciona diferente de banco de dados relacionais. É aconselhável você **NÃO** fechar a conexão durante o uso do aplicativo, somente fazer isso quando ele for fechado.

A conexão está sendo feita por que você está **EXECUTANDO** o código. Não é possível realizar a conexão se o código não for chamado. O que você deve fazer é colocado em um arquivo diferente e no arquivo que você irá usa-lo, usar require.

mongo.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bancodedados', { useNewUrlParser: true })
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

module.exports = mongoose
```

No arquivo que você irá usar (model), você faz:

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('../mongo')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  }
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = User
```

E quando você precisa acessar User, faça:

```
const User = require('../database/models/user')

User.find({})
```

Sobre não cometer erros bobos, isso é normal, já que você está aprendendo. É como uma criança que ao aprender falar, primeiro fala 'mama' ou 'papa' antes de falar 'mamãe' ou 'papai'. Talvez só de usar um ESLINT já te ajude a limitar alguns erros comuns, e ajuda a manter um padrão em todo o projeto.

Comment: Amigo, agradeço muito as dicas, andei pesquisando sobre o ESLINT, pois não o conhecia, vou usa-lo com certeza, obrigado!!